# CreateJS - why mousemove is called?

Tags: events, createjs, mousemove

I don't need mousemove event.

But there are a lot of mousemove calls in the browser profiler.

I trying use removeAllEventListeners() to all createjs.Stage, but this does not work.

[image: browser profiler]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After create new Stage, must call

```
stage.enableDOMEvents(false)
```